# PHP Get currency unit using regex expression

Tags: php, regex

I have some string as:

```
€/£/$400
£/$/£400
€/$400
£/$400
$400
```

How can I get currency unit before these number, using regex - PHP:

For example:

```
String0= "€/£/$400 + 50 free spins" -> Get €/£/$   
String1= "€/£/$400" -> Get €/£/$
String2= "£/$/£400" -> Get £/$/£
String3= "€/$400" -> Get €/$
String4= "£/$400" -> Get £/$
String5= "$400" -> Get $
String5= "£400" -> Get £
Update: String6= "50 free spins" -> Get null;
```

I guess using one regex function to strip this string could do the job.

I'm using `preg_match_all('/\D+/', $str, $matches);`, it's show ok for currency unit, But for now I want to add case: String6 on above. Please help me improving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just strip all the numbers using `preg_replace`:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $input);
```

OR else keep just allowed characters:

```
$repl = preg_replace('#[^€/£$]+#u', '', $input);
```

Comment: The 2-nd variant is better, as `preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $input);` won't give the correct result for `"€/£/$400 + 50 free spins"`

Comment: @user4035: Yes thats correct, earlier I thought inputs were all in the first section of the question.

Comment: Thanks for these quick answer

I updated the question to get " " space character for a string that don't container €/£/$.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead:

```
<?php
$str = "€/£/$0400 + 50 free spins";
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/(.*?)(?=\d)/u', $str, $matches))
{
    print $matches[1];
}

//output:  €/£/$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = preg_replace('/(^[€\/£$]+).+/u', '$1', $input);
```